# How to update a date field as string using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection, which is having a ISO date filed. I want to update that a string.
Eg:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cac3f2eb54f8647d472730e"),
"date" : ISODate("2018-12-20T18:30:00.000Z")
}
```

I want to update this into

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cac3f2eb54f8647d472730e"),
"date" : "2018-12-20"
}
```

I tried the below

```
updateMany(
        {}, 
        {"$set": { "date": { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } } }}
    )
```

while doing aggregate its showing

```
aggregate([
                 {$addFields: {convertedDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }}}])
```

Comment: Do you want to update all documents? if yes then use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: I don't want a separate collection. I want to update in the same collection

Comment: You can change the collection after the updation using `$out`  but cannot update the same document with its own  field value. You have to do using two queries one for find and one for update. Otherwise not possible